# Script not showing properly inside a div tabbertab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added an Instagram Widget inside a div tabbertab. The widget is not shown properly, it is like cutted in the middle. If I put the widget code outside the div tab it works fine, but I need it inside.

Here is a link to my page code:
http://thebestwineriesoftheworld.com/chateausmithhautlafitte/chateausmithhautlafitte.htm

Please let me know what can I do. You can see the widget inside the "Social Networks" title of the tab.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the page is supposed to look like. What I do notice however is that you have an entire page inside of that tab. You have new `<html>`, `<body>`, etc tags. This could be causing part of the problem. You shouldn't have multiple `<html>` tags in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you included this widget, but if you can, you should increase the height of the ifream to sth like `height: 435px;` !

If you don't have access to `ifream` tag, you can do it with js simply :)

Comment: I think that the iframe is actually too tall. Try setting the height to 100%, rather than using px. This makes it look better.

Comment: @blackandorangecat I mean the instagram part ifream !

Comment: It seems is not actually a matte of height. Its something related with the DIV. If i duplicate the widget code outside the DIV look what it happens. Its weird. See now the div and the webpage at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned,The height of the iframe that hold your instagram widget is set to `435px`; Setting a height to 100% relative the the parent container will works a s expected

Example

```
<iframe id="79e8ff18932e6ecaa0a98250d72af257fd095aacd53bb71d709c79dfee180135" style="border: 0px none; width: 450px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%;" scrolling="no" src="https://instawidget.net/embed?u=79e8ff18932e6ecaa0a98250d72af257fd095aacd53bb71d709c79dfee180135" frameborder="no"></iframe>
```

Add the css rule to your stylsheet

```
#79e8ff18932e6ecaa0a98250d72af257fd095aacd53bb71d709c79dfee180135{
height:100%
}
```

Comment: Thanks you repzero. I have done it and it looks fine. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Welcome... feel free to accept answer if the solution meets all your requirements... :D :D